# Maximal subgroups of PSL(n,q)

Tags: gr.group-theory

Dear All,

Does someone know some source for detail description of maximal subgroups of $PSL(n,q)$ , and their indices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at Michael Aschbacher's paper "On the maximal subgroups of the finite classical groups" in Invent. Math. 76 1984, 469-514. If you can't access it through your university, you could find on pages 3-4 of http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.46.9218&rep=rep1&type=ps a statement of Aschbacher's theorem in case of the PGL that might be helpful for you.

Comment: If you prefer pdf to postscript, try http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.46.9218&rep=rep1&type=pdf instead.